# IF - Else statement wont work

Tags: c, if-statement

why my if else if else if statement is not working?

```
   printf ("Enter 1 for midtern1 sorting , 2 for midterm2 sorting , 3 for final sorting\n");
   scanf ("%d",sort);

   if (sort=1){
      midterm1(x);
      for (i=9;i>=0;i--){
      printf ("%s %s %d\n",x[i].name,x[i].surname,x[i].mid1);}}
   else if (sort=2){
        midterm2(x);
        for (i=9;i>=0;i--){
        printf ("%s %s %d\n",x[i].name,x[i].surname,x[i].mid2);}}
   else if (sort=3){
        final(x);
        for (i=9;i>=0;i--){
        printf ("%s %s %d\n",x[i].name,x[i].surname,x[i].final);}}
```

i tried (sort==1), (sort<=1) but still same result.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What do you expect to happen? And what's happening instead?

Comment: if i use (sort=1) it prints the first if but if i enter 2 it still prints the 1 but if i use (sort==1), (sort==2), (sort==3), it just skips and wont print anything.

Comment: Modern compilers usually warn about the trap in which you have fallen. Did you switch on all the warning options of your compiler?

Comment: i am using Dev-C++ , i didn't know that there is option for that, i am trying to find if there is any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two problems:

**(1)** Instead of

```
 if (sort=1)
```

you probably want

```
 if (sort==1)
```

similar for all of your `if`-statements. Reminder, `'='` is assignment, `'=='` is used for Boolean comparisons.

**(2)**

```
scanf ("%d", sort);
             ^
```

needs `&`

```
scanf ("%d", &sort);
             ^
```

Both of these are unfortunately common problems/mistakes .. if you crank up the warning level of your compiler, it may help you avoid some of these.

Comment: its not working , it skips whole if else cycle and ends the code.

Comment: @Cagurtay You also need this: `scanf ("%d", &sort);` -- the `&` is important

Comment: bah i feel so stupid , Thank you and i am sorry for pointless question :(.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `==` instead of `=`. The first one is comparsion, the second one is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sort=1){
```

needs to be

```
if (sort==1){
```

In your code, you're just *assigning* `sort` the value of `1` rather than *comparing*.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple else if statements can often be made more readable by replacing them with a switch case statement - see here for syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else has stated you need to use `==` rather than `=` for EVERY if/else if statement.

You should also look at bUKaneer's suggestion about using a `switch` statement in this situation

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect

```
scanf ("%d",sort);
```

`scanf` requires a *pointer to the variable* where the value is to be stored. Changed it to

```
scanf ("%d",&sort);
```

Also, all your comparisons in the `if-else if` statements are incorrect. Use comparison (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`).

Consider replacing the `if-else if` statements with a `switch - case` construct instead, it'll improve readability.